# How to use Pandas to do a conditional VLOOKUP using two columns as an index for the VLOOKUP?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I'm pretty new to Pandas and Python, and I simply cannot figure out how to do something that is very easily done in Excel.  I was hoping to get a bit of help from the community.

Assume I have the following, which is a df relating to fantasy football that has three columns - 'Name', 'Year', and 'FantasyPts'. Code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Tom Brady', 'Tom Brady', 'Tom Brady', 'Patrick Mahomes', 'Patrick Mahomes', 'Patrick Mahomes'],
                   'Year': [2019, 2018, 2017, 2019, 2018, 2017],
                   'FantasyPts': [300, 350, 400, 500, 400, 50],
                   })
```

I want to add another column to the table called 'FantasyPtsPreviousYear' but am having a ton of difficulty figuring out how to do so in Pandas / Python.

What I want to do is:

1. For each row in the table, have python / pandas check the name and year in that row of the df.
2. Look up the fantasy points scored by the same player in the previous year (i.e., Year - 1)
3. Populate that number in a new row of the df called 'FantasyPtsPreviousYear' or, if there is no data for the previous year for that player, enter 0.

In Excel, I would simply create new columns and use those columns with VLOOKUPs.  The closest thing I have been able to find to VLOOKUP in Pandas is merge but that doesn't seem to work here (or at least I can't figure out how to make it work with this specific application).  After trying to find the answer, I think it might have something to do with the loc() function and a For loop, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks for any help you can provide!  I greatly appreciate it and think this community is awesome for all of the assistance it provides!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` the DataFrame with itself where you add 1 to the year. This explicitly defines the match on Year -> Year-1 for each player

(Be careful with `shift`, unless you are *certain* you have a row for every year. Without explicitly reindexing to all years a `shift` within group will give you the last year you have data for, regardless of whether that is 1 year ago or 10 years ago (if missing data))

---

```
df = df.merge((df.assign(Year=df['Year']+1)
                 .rename(columns={'FantasyPts': 'FantasyPts_prev'})), 
              how='left', on=['Name', 'Year'])
df['FantasyPts_prev'] = df['FantasyPts_prev'].fillna(0, downcast='infer')

              Name  Year  FantasyPts  FantasyPts_prev
0        Tom Brady  2019         300              350
1        Tom Brady  2018         350              400
2        Tom Brady  2017         400                0
3  Patrick Mahomes  2019         500              400
4  Patrick Mahomes  2018         400               50
5  Patrick Mahomes  2017          50                0
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I didn't even realize the issue you flagged (using shift when I don't have a row for every year) and greatly appreciate you flagging it so it doesn't trip me up with a different data set without rows for every year.  After reading your comment, I added another row to the df as follows: df = df.append({'Name': 'Tom Brady', 'Year': 2011, 'FantasyPts': 450}, ignore_index=True) and realized that your solution still works, while shift seems to deliver the error that you mentioned above.  Thank you very much for your reply!  Tremendously helpful!

Comment: May I edit / suggest adding the `fillna(0)` at the end to fully match OP's output? I also want to thank you for pointing out the issue with using shift, it's really important to take it into consideration as it might ruin the whole analysis!

Comment: @CeliusStingher yeah in the future feel free to edit. It will notify me anyway and then if I disagree I can resolve it in the edit

Answer (score 3):

I believe this can be achieved with a combination of `where()` and `shift()`. However, this requires the data to be previously sorted. Here is the code given the data you provide:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name','Year'],ascending=[True,True])
df['FantasyPtsPreviousYear'] = df['FantasyPts'].shift().where(df['Name'].eq(df['Name'].shift())).fillna(0)
print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
              Name  Year  FantasyPts  FantasyPtsPreviousYear
5  Patrick Mahomes  2017          50                     0.0
4  Patrick Mahomes  2018         400                    50.0
3  Patrick Mahomes  2019         500                   400.0
2        Tom Brady  2017         400                     0.0
1        Tom Brady  2018         350                   400.0
0        Tom Brady  2019         300                   350.0
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this quick and helpful reply!  I was able this to work well on my data set.  The only issue was what @ALollz mentioned below.  I realize this wasn't in my original example df, but if I had added another row to my data set like this:  df = df.append({'Name': 'Tom Brady', 'Year': 2011, 'FantasyPts': 450}, ignore_index=True), then the Tom Brady 2017 'FantasyPtsPreviousYear' column comes back as 450 (Brady's 2011 stats) rather than 0 or NaN.  Is there a way to fix this?  Either way, thank you VERY much for your extremely helpful and prompt reply.  I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you for also replying to my answer, I suggest you use **ALollz** approach as it tackles better the issue of the missing years, this straightforward solution might be easier however, it has more limitations as it would work for the case all the years from start to end are in the dataframe and correctly sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `groupby` with `shift`

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name','Year'],ascending=[True,True])
df['FantasyPtsPreviousYear'] = df['FantasyPts'].groupby(df['Name']).shift().fillna(0)
```

Comment: I'd suggest tweaking this to `df['FantasyPts'].groupby(df['Name']).shift(periods=1, fill_value=0)`

Comment: Thanks very much! And thanks also to Ben for his suggestion! I was able this to work well on my data set. The only issue was what @ALollz mentioned below. I realize this wasn't in my original example df, but if I had added another row to my data set like this: df = df.append({'Name': 'Tom Brady', 'Year': 2011, 'FantasyPts': 450}, ignore_index=True), then the Tom Brady 2017 'FantasyPtsPreviousYear' column comes back as 450 (Brady's 2011 stats) rather than 0 or NaN. Is there a way to fix this? Either way, thank you VERY much for your extremely helpful and prompt reply. I greatly appreciate it!